# How to sum a field for all records and then return the max of all summed records with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to return the record with the max value after all records have been grouped and then summed.  I am able to get the sum but not return the full record of the max value.

This is what I have so far, how would I get the max summed value?

```
from es in EmployeeSkills
group es by es.Employee.FirstName + " " + es.Employee.LastName into empGroup
select new
{
    Name = empGroup.Key,
    YOE = (from y in empGroup select y.YearsOfExperience).Sum ()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method

```
var query=from es in EmployeeSkills
          group es by es.Employee.FirstName + " " + es.Employee.LastName into empGroup
          select new
          {
            Name = empGroup.Key,
            YOE = empGroup.Select(y=>y.YearsOfExperience).Sum()
          };

var result=query.Aggregate((seed, current)=>current.YOE>seed.YOE?current:seed);
```

Or you could also use `MaxBy` extension method from [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) library:

```
var result=query.MaxBy(e=>e.YOE);
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. Where you have `e` it should be `current`.